# Add To Cart button Text Change Based on Discount

Tags: woocommerce

This will change the text into "Add again?" when the customer clicks "Add to cart" and I'm wondering how to change this into applying a discount each time the button is clicked.

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_add_to_cart_again' );
function woo_add_to_cart_again() {

    global $woocommerce;
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            return __('Add Again', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
}
```

When clicked the first time, add to cart as normal but change the button text into "Buy again & Get 5% OFF", after pressed the 2nd time, text changes into "Buy 3 and get 10% OFF" and the discount should apply to the product, not the cart.

I would like for this to be a checkbox option beside "Downloadable" in WooCommerce Admin when creating a new product. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: basically you want to check if the product in cart is equal 1 then massages will be Buy again & Get 5% OFF if 2 in cart  "Buy 3 and get 10% OFF" right or you want it  to add event listener on click ? and then add the discount accordingly

Comment: As long as the button text changes based on qty in cart and that it applies the discount, either way is okay for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first to change the text based on the quantity i just added an if condition to your function to check the quantity for that specific product in the cart and change the text accordingly as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_add_to_cart_again' );
function woo_add_to_cart_again() {

    global $woocommerce;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $values['quantity'] == 1 && get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            return __( 'Buy again & Get 5% OFF', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        if ( $values['quantity'] == 2 && get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            return __( 'Buy 3 and get 10% OFF', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        if ( $values['quantity'] > 2 && get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            return __( 'Add Again', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

**Note:** if you want to change the text in the archive page too you can use `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` hook and added it to the above code as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_add_to_cart_again' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_add_to_cart_again' );
```

Then we need to calculate the price for those products which is qualified for the discount and add the discount based on the product prices.

We are going to use `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` to insert this discount to our cart as follow :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount' );


function add_discount( WC_Cart $cart ) {

    $discounts = []; //Store the disocunts in array 
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $values['quantity'] == 2 ) {
            // Calculate the discount amount  
            $product_price = ( $_product->get_sale_price() ) ? $_product->get_sale_price() : $_product->get_regular_price();
            $price         = $product_price * 2;
            array_push( $discounts, $price * 0.05 ); //Push the discount 

        }

        if ( $values['quantity'] > 2 ) {
            // Calculate the discount amount  
            $product_price = ( $_product->get_sale_price() ) ? $_product->get_sale_price() : $_product->get_regular_price();
            $price         = $product_price * $values['quantity'];
            $discount      = $price * 0.1;
            array_push( $discounts, $price * 0.1 );//Push the discount 
        }
    }

    $cart->add_fee( 'Your Disocunt', -array_sum( $discounts ) );

}
```

**Updated:**

To Change the add_to_cart text when using Ajax actually it's already answered in here By @LoicTheAztec at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471293/relabel-add-to-cart-button-after-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce)  and with little modification you can achieve your target goal as follow:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_add_to_cart_jquery' );
function change_add_to_cart_jquery() {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) : ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                $('a.add_to_cart_button').click(function () {
                    $this = $(this);
                    if (typeof $($this).attr('data-qty') == 'undefined') {
                        $($this).text('Buy again & Get 5% OFF');
                        $($this).attr('data-qty', 1);
                        return;
                    }
                    if ($($this).attr('data-qty') == 1) {
                        $($this).text('Buy 3 and get 10% OFF');
                        $($this).attr('data-qty', 2);
                        return
                    }
                    $($this).text('Add Again');
                });

            })(jQuery);
            </script>
        <?php
        endif;
}
```

of course the code above has been tested.

Comment: Thank you! Works very well. Would be even better if the button changed on the archive without having to update (refresh) the page. But that's a minor thing. Again, thank you. How to make this into a checkbox button so that the functionality can be "activated" per product basis?

As I mention in my original question: "I would like for this to be a checkbox option beside "Downloadable" in WooCommerce Admin when creating a new product."

Comment: @bjornen you are welcome i will think about easy solution for that give me 10 min

Comment: sure thing. I'll wait :) Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @bjornen i have updated my answer sorry for delay :)

Comment: Cool! I didn't refresh :) Thank you and thank you LoicTheAztec so much. It works fine :)

Comment: Only thing missing, if you know how, is to make it into a checkbox on the WooCommerce admin so that it can be activated on a product level. It's cool as hell, but having it for all products might not be ideal :)

Comment: @bjornen  yes of course but I left my office I u want post a question and in the morning if no one answer u I will do it

Comment: Please have a look at checkbox feature when you can @kashalo. Really appreciate it.

Comment: hello again kashalo, I hate to ask again (feel like I'm spamming), but do you want me to make a new question about adding this as a checkbox although it's in the original question?

Please let me know. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181148/discussion-between-kashalo-and-bjornen).