# Change custom Ajax Add to Cart button text after add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I use a code that changes the text and style of the "Add to Cart" button for a product if the item is already in the cart. Many thanks to 7uc1f3r for this.

```
/* for single product */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'single_product_button_text' );
 
function single_product_button_text( $text ) {
 
    if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        $text = 'Product in cart';
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}
 
/* for archive/category pages */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'products_button_text', 20, 2 );
 
function products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
 
    if( 
       $product->is_type( 'simple' )
       && $product->is_purchasable()
       && $product->is_in_stock()
       && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
    ) {
 
        $text = 'Product in cart';
 
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}

function action_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var selector = '.add_to_cart_text:contains("Product in cart")';
            
            // Selector contains specific text
            if ( $( selector ).length > 0 ) {
                $( selector ).addClass( 'product-is-added' );
            } else {
                $( selector ).removeClass( 'product-is-added' );            
            }
            
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
```

After adding a product to the cart, I have to refresh the page each time to get new text and button style.

**UPDATE**

I also used *[Relabel "add to cart" button after add to cart in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471293/relabel-add-to-cart-button-after-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce/47474327#47474327)* 2nd function code to change the text and style of the button using AJAX. The text changes, but all styles break.

Unfortunately, adding styles on the `echo '<div class="add_to_cart_text">' . $new_text . '</div>';` line doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your website shop and archives pages are very custom (doesn't have the default WooCommerce html structure) you need a very custom jQuery code made for your website.

Your Ajax add to cart button has by default this output html example:

```
<a href="?add-to-cart=1234" rel="nofollow" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="1234" class="add-to-cart-grid btn-link nasa-tip add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_simple nasa-tiped" data-product_sku="AB123" data-tip="Add to Cart">
    <span class="add_to_cart_text">Add to Cart</span>
    <i class="cart-icon pe-7s-cart"></i>
</a>
```

And you need on Ajax added to cart to have the following output html (example):

```
<a href="?add-to-cart=1234" rel="nofollow" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="1234" class="add-to-cart-grid btn-link nasa-tip add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_simple nasa-tiped" data-product_sku="AB123" data-tip="Product in cart">
    <span class="add_to_cart_text product-is-added">Product in cart</span>
    <i class="cart-icon pe-7s-cart"></i>
</a>
```

So know we can manage the jQuery code that is needed for your custom Ajax add to cart buttons on shop and archive pages…

Try the following that will change the text on your custom Ajax add to cart button on `added_to_cart` WooCommerce jQuery event:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_button_text_js_script' );
function ajax_button_text_js_script() {
    $text = __('Product in cart', 'woocommerce');
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>',      $this;

            $(document.body).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart', function(event){
                $this = $(this); // Get button jQuery Object and set it in a variable
            });

            $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function(event,b,data){
                var buttonText = '<span class="add_to_cart_text product-is-added">'+text+'</span><i class="cart-icon pe-7s-cart"></i>';

                // Change inner button html (with text) and Change "data-tip" attribute value
                $this.html(buttonText).attr('data-tip',text);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar implemented on a website.

What might help is

`.on('input change', function() { // Your code here }).change();`

this updated my product page in real time and I believe you should be able to find a way to implement it to change the text on the add to cart button.

I am new to JavaScript so please bear with me and I hope my answer was at least a little helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. In my case, the name "Product in Cart" is changed using AJAX without reloading the page, only the style of the button breaks. I just need the correct code to save the style of the button.